# I need to calculate 1st and 3rd quartile in csv file without using numpy and pandas

Tags: python, python-3.7

File looks like 3 columns of integer numbers. This is what I have
But it is returning me TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

```
import statistics

file = open("PokemonF.csv","r")
first_col=[]
sec_col=[]
third_col=[]
columns=[first_col]
for line in file :
    data = line.split(',')
    first_col.append(int(data[0]))
    sec_col.append(int(data[1]))
    third_col.append(int(data[2]))
for col_ in columns:
    min_col = min(first_col)
    sortedData = sorted(first_col)
    mid = len(first_col)/2
    if len(sortedData) % 2 == 0:
        lowerQ = statistics.median(sortedData[:mid])
        upperQ = statistics.median(sortedData[mid:])
    else:  
        lowerQ = statistics.median(sortedData[:mid])
        upperQ = statistics.median(sortedData[mid+1:])
    median_col = statistics.median(first_col)
    max_col = max(first_col)


    print("Minimum: {}".format(min_col))
    print("First quartile: {}".format(lowerQ))
    print("Median: {}".format(median_col))
    print("Maximum: {}".format(max_col))
file.close
```

Comment: `mid = len(first_col)/2` might give something like `mid = 5.5` when you have an odd column length.  You might want to `floor(mid)` or some other way of rounding mid to an integer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your input file shouldn't be here at all: simply hard-code the results of the first `for` loop.

Comment: Also note that your `close` attempt is invalid: you referenced the function as a whole instead of calling it.  You need the parentheses: `file.close()`.  Also, use a different name for that variable: `file` is a pre-defined type.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test the solution since you failed to provide a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I think I see your problem:

```
mid = len(first_col)/2
if ...
    lowerQ = statistics.median(sortedData[:mid])
    upperQ = statistics.median(sortedData[mid:])
```

If `first_col` has an odd quantity of elements, then `mid` is a float value, such as 7.5.  You can't use that as a string slice index.  Try integer division instead:

```
mid = len(first_col) // 2
```

Depending on your local definition of "quartile" boundary, you may need to add 1.